# How to determine the function of a data list?

Tags: functions, physics, graphing-functions

I'll be the first to admit, I am not a math wiz. That said, please forgive my ignorance. I need to write a script for work that will take a given temperature/pressure and output the other (pressure/temperature). How do I find the function of the data?

Comment: Try regression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: On the other hand, the ideal gas assumption might not hold for certain regimes of pressure/temperature, in which case equations of state that account for nonideality (e.g. van der Waals, Redlich-Kwong) might be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should plot the data to see what it looks like.  The ideal gas law suggests that if you have a closed volume and fixed amount of gas, the pressure will be proportional to the temperature.  Excel will run a linear regression to give a straight line fit through the data and give you the equation of the line, so you could try that first.  Excel will also do a higher order polynomial fit if the errors in the straight line fit are too large.